# How to pass an instance of Core Data ManagedObjectContext to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller

EDIT: I've managed to figure it out with the help of the guys who commented on my question. Big thanks to everyone! I've updated the code in the question for everyone who might find himself in the same position as me.

I have a User entity with 6 properties.

```
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var activityLevel: String
    @NSManaged var age: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var gender: String
    @NSManaged var goal: String
    @NSManaged var height: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var weight: NSNumber

    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, name: String, age: Int, gender: String) -> User {

        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! User

        newUser.name = name
        newUser.age = age
        newUser.gender = gender

        return newUser
    }

}
```

I want to initialise three of them (name, age and gender) in one VC and the rest on a second one.

Here's how my first view controller looks like. I have a mainUser variable which I want to send to the second VC through for prepareForSegue method. I've been trying to get this to work but to no end. Is there any standard practice for doing so?

Also... Here's my First VC in case you need it:

```
class PersonalDataViewController: UIViewController {

    var mainUser: User?
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    // MARK: UI Elements
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInputField: CustomUITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageInputField: CustomUITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderSelector: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var proceedButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func proceedButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    }



    func determineGender(control: UISegmentedControl) -> String {
        var gender: String?

        switch control.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            gender = "male"
        case 1:
            gender = "female"
        default:
            break;
        }
        return gender!

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toFitnessData" {

            var fitnessDataVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FitnessDataViewController

            fitnessDataVC.currentUser = User.createInManagedObjectContext(

                self.managedObjectContext!,
                name: nameInputField.text,
                age: ageInputField.text.toInt()!,
                gender: determineGender(genderSelector)

            )

        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And here's the second ViewController for anyone that is interested... Can't really see where my mistake is.

```
class FitnessDataViewController: UIViewController {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    @IBOutlet weak var greetingsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightInputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightInputField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityLevelSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var goalSelector: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func readyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        finishUserInitialization()
    }

    var currentUser: User?


    func finishUserInitialization() {

        if let user = currentUser as User! {

            user.weight = weightInputField.text.toInt()!
            user.height = heightInputField.text.toInt()!
            user.activityLevel = determineActivityLevel(activityLevelSelector)
            user.goal = determineGoal(goalSelector)

            println(user)

        }

    }

    func determineActivityLevel(selector: UISegmentedControl) -> String {

        var activityLevel: String?

        switch selector.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            activityLevel = "sedetary"
        case 1:
            activityLevel = "light"
        case 2:
            activityLevel = "moderate"
        case 3:
            activityLevel = "veryActive"
        case 4:
            activityLevel = "extremelyActive"
        default:
            break;
        }

        return activityLevel!

    }

    func determineGoal(selector: UISegmentedControl) -> String {

        var goal: String?

        switch selector.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            goal = "looseWeight"
        case 1:
            goal = "maintainWeight"
        case 2:
            goal = "gainWeight"
        default:
            break;
        }

        return goal!

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: try setting retainsRegisteredObjects From doc - A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver keeps strong references to all registered managed objects.

Comment: Do you get an error with the above code?

Comment: @pbasdf When I try to println() the result of currentUser in the second view controller's viewDidLoad it says "nil" :/

Comment: Curious. Your code looks fine.  What about if you println in the prepareForSegue?

Comment: Assume your `destinationViewController` has a public variable (declared in its header file) `currentUser`?

Comment: @pbasdf Oddly enough println-ing in the prepareForSegue results in nil too!

Comment: @andrewbuilder I added the code of my second VC above. But yes... it's a public var.

Comment: Is your segue linked to the same button as `proceedButtonPressed`?  They may be running in the wrong order.

Comment: @pbasdf Now it wasn't! Initially I thought self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFitnessData", sender: sender) would solve the problem as per your suggestion. Weirdness -> println(mainUser) from the first VC now results in 2 entries - one is nil and the other is the object I actually initialised. So the segue gets executed twice??? And as for the println() in the second VC - nil again. Thanks for your help so far man! Really appreciate it. Oh... Again - I updated my first VC.

Comment: Ok.  It sounds like you have hooked up the button to the segue in your storyboard, as well as calling performSeque, hence the two log entries.  To test, remove the performSeque, and move the createNewUser call from proceedButtonPressed to the prepareForSegue function.

Comment: @pbasdf That seemed to have worked :) Thank you so much for your valuable input, I really appreciate it. You have a cold beer from me if you ever find yourself in Berlin. It just felt unnatural for me to move that sort of logic into the prepareForSegue method... I'll try and find a cleaner approach in the future. It works well for now though. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  One cleaner approach would be to link the segue from the view controller itself, rather than the button, then use performSegueWithIdentifier in the IBAction code (after the createNewUser call!). FYI, it's better to add (and accept) your own answer to a question, rather than to edit the question to include the solution.